# Fine art to hint somebody to accept an answer which was voted positively

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer, new-users, up-votes

I now had several times the situation that I provided an answer on Stack Overflow to a question from another user which was suited for having been the accepted answer.

My answer was either the only one and voted positively or voted positively compared to other answers.
I put some effort into providing a good answer.
However, I got thanks and then the user forgot about the answer.

Is it good manners to kindly hint the user to accept that answer within a comment, if there wasn't any better answer?

Comment: Some people will add a comment to the question reminding OP to accept an answer. But it looks best if it’s someone else that does this. OP also often doesn’t see the comment if they don’t visit the site again. Fact is, this will happen. Sometimes I’ve had an answer accepted many months later, but also many answers remain with a “thank you, that solves it” comment but no accept.

Comment: What matters is that your answer is there for future visitors. Make sure to answer those questions you think will be useful to many, not the ones that apply uniquely to OP, and then it doesn’t matter if your answer is accepted or not.

Comment: I see one needs a little bit patience from what you said about receiving accepts months later. About your second comment: I selected to answer questions which did not appear to be too complicated and which i felt confident about but i did not follow any strategy other than that.